# Where in this argument ultrafilter is used?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, filters

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem#section_1

Let's first not assume any choice principle.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $\beta_1,\beta_2$ be bases for $V$.

Suppose $\beta_1\succ \beta_2$.

Let $I$ and $J$ be indexing sets for $\beta_1,\beta_2$ respectively, so that $\beta_1=\{u_i:i\in I\}$ and $\beta_2=\{v_j:j\in J\}$

For each $j\in J$, let $E_j$ be the unique finite subset of $I$ and $C_j\triangleq \{a_{j_i}\}_{i\in E_j}$ be the unique subset of $F$ such that $v_j=\sum_{i\in E_j} a_{j_i} u_{j_i}$ and $\forall i\in E_j, a_{j_i}≠0$.

(Since unique representation theorem can be proved in ZF, choice is not used till now.)

Thus, $\{(E_j,C_j)\}_{j\in J}$ is a family of distinct sets so that $\{(E_j,C_j)\}_{j\in J}\approx J$.

Now, I want to claim that $\bigcup_{j\in J} E_j \prec I$. I see choice is in need here, but why ultrafilter lemma?

Moreover, does ultrafilter lemma imply that every set is comparable? (You don't need to explain this to me, I just want to know if it is or not..:))

Comment: Small comments: 1. You may want to indicate that $A\preceq B$ means that $A$ injects into $B$, and $A\prec B$ means that $A\preceq B$, but not *vice versa*. 2. $C_j$ is a *sequence*, rather than a set. 3. The $E_j$ do not need to be distinct; all you can say from what you have written is that the *pairs* $(E_j,C_j)$ are distinct as $j$ varies. If I understand, is your question how to prove that $\bigcup_j E_j\prec I$ assuming the ultrafilter lemma? And, is your second question whether the ultrafilter lemma implies that *any two* sets are comparable? (The answer to this is no.)

Comment: @Andres 1.That is exactly what i meant. Is there a common notation for this rather than $\prec$? 2. $C_j$ is not a sequence. To make $(E_j,C_j)$ distinct as $j$ varies, i took $C_j$ to be a finite subset of a sequence that represents $v_j$, whose elements are all nonzero. 3. Yes, I was asking how to prove that $\bigcup_{j\in J} E_j \prec I$, assuming ultrafilter lemma. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Andres I got it. Please never mind my comment just above.. I was so foolish..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sketch of the proof that all bases have the same cardinality, assuming only ZF + the Boolean prime ideal theorem (which is equivalent to ZF + the ultrafilter lemma, and is strictly weaker than ZFC) is given here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93242/sizes-of-bases-of-vector-spaces-without-the-axiom-of-choice/93359#93359. The proof is not at all obvious from what it says on the Wikipedia page.

I should mention that if you do not want to use full AC, then you should not start by saying "suppose $\beta_1 \succ \beta_2$" or even "suppose $\beta_1 \succeq \beta_2$".  The goal of the proof is to *construct* injections between the bases.

Comment: I'm amused how a lot of AC references go back to me somehow... just yesterday an answer on MO references an answer of mine here... :-)